# Cleaning save as dialogue

Tags: finder

I've been searching the last couple of days for a way to clean up the save as dialogue box. More importantly the favorites portion. There are a bunch of dmg files that are no longer mounted and should not be there. They do not show up in finder only when I try to save a file.

So far I tried resetting finder, cleaning with ccleaner and scoured through plist with Pref Setter application, to no avail. I have attached a screen shot of what I'm trying to clean.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you only see this in your browser?

Comment: the list shows up on all application not just the browser.

Answer (score 1):

These items are defined in the side bar in your finder. Open a new Finder and make sure the Sidebar is shown (if not, go to **View** menu and select **Show Sidebar**) and you should see the same items listed there.

[image]

You can right click on any of those items and select **Remove from Sidebar**. That should do the trick.

Comment: I should have posted that picture too. but its clean there as well.